# C Code showing- Stack Trace: user_code.out: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion

Tags: c

Can anybody help me with this code: I was trying running it but the compiler popped up with:

**Stack Trace: user_code.out: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.**

I have no idea what this error is about or how do I solve it.

***Please Give Solution***

```
main() {
  unsigned int location = 1, c, x;
  long int * A, n, t;
  scanf("%d", & t);
  while (t--) {
    scanf("%d", & n);
    A = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      scanf("%d", (A + i));

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == j)
          continue;
        else {
          x = ((A[i] & A[j]) ^ (A[i] | A[j]));
          if (x < c)
            c = x;
        }
      }
    }
    printf("%d", c);
    free(A);
  }
}
```

Comment: You malloc space for `n` ints (and `scanf` into it using `%d`), but `A` is a pointer to `long int`.

Comment: Because of this, you corrupt the heap, and that happened to manifest as some failed assertions in malloc.

Comment: Same for `scanf("%d", &t)` and `scanf("%d", &n);` and I'm surprised that the compiler didn't produce warnings for these.

Comment: A decent compiler *does* produce warnings for these: https://godbolt.org/z/bfMTn5xrs.  OP: Use a decent compiler, turn on its warnings, and don't ignore them!  (Also: I suggest proper indentation and more meaningful variable names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that

```
A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

allocates space for `n` objects with the size of `int`, and you later refer to this memory through a pointer to objects of size `long int`. If these types are not the same size, you run the risk of reading and writing with incorrect memory sizes.

A good practice is to use the identifier with the `sizeof` operator

```
array = malloc(sizeof *array * length);
```

so that if the type of `array` changes, the expression here does not need to.

The `"%d"` conversion specifier for `scanf` expects an `int`. For `long int`, you'll need `"%ld"`. For `unsigned int`, you'll need `"%u"`.

Additionally, `c` is never initialized, and thus

```
if(x<c)
```

will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by reading the value of it.

Other issues:

- There are two signatures for `main` that you should use:

  1. `int main(void)`, or
  2. `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or equivalent).
- You should **not** [cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965).
- `scanf` can *fail*, and you should be prepared to handle these events.
- The proper type for storing sizes of objects is `size_t`. This should be used when iterating on array indices.
- Using signed types for sizes and iteration counts can lead to strange edge cases.
- Coding style is subjective, but I'm willing to bet most would find the style of this code to be very hard to read. Be smart, not clever - try to use more meaningful variable names, use clear and consistent indentation, and don't be so afraid of the spacebar.

---

A more complete example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void die(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned int andxoror(long int a, long int b) {
    return (a & b) ^ (a | b);
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned int lowest, calculation, times;
    long int *array;
    size_t length;

    printf("Input number of repetitions: ");

    if (scanf("%u", &times) != 1)
        die("Invalid repetition input.");

    while (times--) {
        printf("Input length of array: ");

        if (scanf("%zu", &length) != 1)
            die("Invalid length input.");

        if ((array = malloc(sizeof *array * length)) == NULL)
            die("Could not allocate memory.");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            printf("Input array member %ld of %ld: ", i + 1, length);

            if (scanf("%ld", array + i) != 1) {
                free(array);
                die("Invalid array member input.");
            }
        }

        lowest = UINT_MAX;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            for (size_t j = 1; j < length; j++)
                if (i != j && (calculation = andxoror(array[i], array[j])) < lowest)
                    lowest = calculation;

        printf("Final calculation: %u\n", lowest);
        free(array);
    }
}
```